# having problems with wss over ssl

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am having trouble converting my ws connection into wss. I have 2 types of servers running on my code. First, I keep a net server that retrieves live data packets. Then, when a client wishes to view this data, I have a web socket server that sends it to them.

My code looks like so:

```
var net = require("net");
var https = require("https");
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    ssl: true,
    port: 8082,
    ssl_key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    ssl_cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
});
var servercsv = net.createServer();
servercsv.listen(9001);

servercsv.on('connection', function(socket){
  fetchlivedata();
});

wss.on('connection', function(ws){
    ws.on('message', function(message){
        ws.send(thelivedata());
    });
});
```

To test this I have this mock client page which is written as follows:

```
<p id="muscovy"></p>
<script>
var muscovy = document.getElementById('muscovy');
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8082');
    var wes = new WebSocket('wss://mywebsite.com:8082');
    // event emmited when connected
    wes.onopen = function (){
        // sending a send event to websocket server
        wes.send("Beans");
    }
    // event emmited when receiving message 
    wes.onmessage = function(ev){
        //let musco = JSON.parse(ev.data);//
        //muscovy.textContent = musco[0][1];//
        let misho = ev.data;
    }
</script>
```

When I run this test I get the following error:

```
Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

The problem is more than likely the implementation of my ssl certificates.

I should also point out that I am following the advice of someone else by converting my original certs (`crt`) to pem. I have done this by changing the extension name. I was told that since my certs have text that begins with `---Begin etc---` that it could be reformatted to pem by doing this.

Would appreciate knowing if this is incorrect. I'm inclined to believe that my web socket server code is the issue here.

EDIT:

I wanted to also mention that my code works over regular web sockets. If I have like so:

```
var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    port: 8082
});
var servercsv = net.createServer();
servercsv.listen(9001);
```

then everything works as intended. But only on non-https environments.

Comment: Does a normal web socket work?

Comment: yes. when i do not include my ssl certs it works. the only problem is when i put my site live, im not allowed to pass ws content over https.

Comment: You mean when your site is live(i.e WAN not localhost) normal web socket works but your production server requirements need secure.

Comment: when i test locally via localhost client connected to my node server, it works because there is no need for wss.

Comment: Also, going through [this example](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/examples/ssl.js) I see the following code: `wss://localhost:${server.address().port}` and am not sure whether this is meant as dummy data, or literal. Are you supposed to change `localhost`, for instance, to `servername.com`? How are ports included here? I am not sure how to assign a port in this example.

Comment: No on that line it's just opening a websocket connection to the websocket server it created to show it works. It's also demonstrating a https server combined with a websocket server on the same port.

Comment: Is your certificate self signed? Or does it need a intermediate? Best way to see if your certificate is all hunky dory dandy you could create a regular webserver over https and see what your browser spits back.

Comment: I got it through godaddy and was able to use it for my previous express server setup.

Comment: Check if the .pem you created includes all intermediates and works correctly. Also there are many more variables ports open, dns, cache

Comment: Please check if you can connect to your none secure websocket server over WAN from a regular http connection. Secure is only required if the protocol is https. This will let you know if you are even able to communicate with the server from the outside.

Comment: Also if your not using a proxy you need to set the host parameter on your websocket server to 0.0.0.0 in your current configuration it will default to localhost only.